# How to display the planets of the solar system to scale?

Tags: math

I have to make the solar system in openGL. The problem is that actual planet distances and sizes are so different that its difficult to draw. I was thinking there must be some way of 'compressing' a series of numbers so that the numbers become closer but their relative differences remain the same. So for instance on one end of the scale the numbers would be as they were, on the other end of the scale all the numbers would have converged on the same value. I know this is just a case of scaling and then adding/subtracting an amount but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What's "difficult"? Do you need more precision or do you need more range? What language are you using?

Comment: For instance the sun is 600 times bigger than pluto, so drawing it would mean the whole screen would be filled with the sun and you wouldn't be able to see pluto

Comment: Notice that you *cannot* have two planets visible at the same time if you are to use the proper length scales. (Of course. Not even nearly.) Furthermore, if you just wish to draw all planets (and the sun) side-by-side on a 2D screen (that is, in a table), you also cannot (reasonably) use the proper ratios of their "diameters".

Comment: I had the same project in university, i think i cheat because i used different scale parameter for scaling the sizes of planets and distances between them. Than for me it was hard to imagine how to put it on thee screen in right scale.

Comment: Note that a factor of 600 can't be fudged away by linear scaling and translation.  Your only choices would be to have the scales vary, or use something like logarithmic scaling.

Comment: [Most depictions of planets to scale](http://www.google.com/images?q=planet+scale) use several views, where each view has the largest planet of the previous view and the smallest planet in the current.  Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: Do you necessarily need to have them all visible simultaneously? Are you talking 2D or 3D? Is this an exercise in astrophysics, or in computer programming? Answers to these questions will heavily influence how you should go about your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you just described is a [logrithmic scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale).

I'm not sure if that's the best option here though.  A better option would be simply having a good UI - draw the planets to scale, with some sort of visual-indicator *(say, a hollow green circle; or a picture of magnifying glass)* of where the smaller planets are.  When the user hovers the mouse over the visual-indicator, enlarge the planet, or zoom in on the planet when they click on it.

Or, give them the option to zoom-in with the mouse-wheel.

Or, simply eyeball it, making sure smaller planets look smaller while larger planets look larger, with a note that the planets are not to scale.

For reference, [here](http://monarchlibrary.wikispaces.com/file/view/solar_system.jpg/128507657/solar_system.jpg) is a typical textbook image, with the planets not to scale, while [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Planets2008.jpg) is what they would look like to scale (the planets, at least, not their orbits).